# Trying to get 3er level laravel relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Let me put the code first..

### Permissions Model

```
class Permission extends Model {
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }

    public function menus()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Menu');
    }
}
```

### Role Model

```
class Role extends Model {

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission');
    }
}
```

### Menu Model

```
class Menu extends Model {
    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Permission');
    }
}
```

### User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable {    
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }

 }
```

Well, 
I'm trying to get something like (assuming that I already got a single user)  `$user->role->permissions->menus`
I'm trying to get role, then the permissions associated with that role and then the menu items that are associated with that permissions.

Idk if i'm explaining myself..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$users = App\User::with('role.permissions.menus')->get();
```

Comment: Meaning you have only four users in your database